# Visual Studio Code line number difficult to read

Tags: format, visual-studio-code, line-numbers

For most dark themes the line number of visual studio code are too dark and difficult to read. How to make it brighter?

That is, how to format the line numbers in terms of font weight, brightness...

Comment: [Change the theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vk6JQwTonXA)

Comment: I don't think this comment answers the question since the OP asks for something more specific. Did +1 since the question is legitimate and helped me.

Comment: A better answer I found was [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1205455/341567).

Answer (score 17):

You could easily change their color and brighten them for your theme via:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#ffff",
}
```

In your setting.json. [vscode reference: theme colors for an editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors)